# IntelliJ IDE how to add SDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

i downloaded the JavaFX SDK from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) but when i try adding it to IntelliJ i get the error "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK".
[Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDK's -> add]

But i cant find an JDK from JavaFX, maybe i'am understanding something wrong between JDK's and SDK's. But IntelliJ says "add SDK" but need's JDK, can i switch it anywhere in the setting's or as i said above am i understanding something wrong.

Thanks in advance

Edit: The solution's beneth worked fine, here's what i found in the mean time [link](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ doesn't make it all that easy to use JavaFX. I find the most intuitive way is to do the following:

1. Add global libraries for the JavaFX modules you want to use. The easiest way is to use `from Maven` and search for `org.openjfx` then add the modules you want (e.g. `controls` and `fxml` for the basic IntelliJ generated JavaFX project).
2. Create a `module-info.java` file for your app that looks something like the code below.

> ```
> module MyModule {
>     requires javafx.controls;
>     requires javafx.fxml;
>     exports mypackage;
> }
> ```

This creates a dependency on the javafx modules and exports your package so that the javafx reflection code has access to it.

There is an alternative method where the dependencies are added to the command line of the app's runtime but I find the method above more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try that tomorrow

Comment: The alternative method I mentioned with paths on the command line is explained in @ublec's answer. Both work though I prefer to make the module dependencies explicit in the project itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked too^^ And, yes this was the more straightforward way

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that the JavaFX plugin is enabled (bundled and default). Then, in a new project, press `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + s` => `Libraries` => `+` => `Java`. Here, find the JavaFX folder you downloaded, then locate the `lib` folder in the JavaFX folder. Click on that, and it shouldn't complain about it not being a valid home. Apply your changes then close the dialog.

Now, in the main menu, hover over `Run` then click `Edit configurations`. Under the applications tab, click `Main` (or whatever your file is called). Then, next to the `Build and Run` section, hover over `Modify options` => `Add VM options`, then, in the text area, write the file path, paste:

```
--module-path /path/to/javafx/sdk --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Make sure you replace `/path/to/javafx/sdk` with the path to the `lib` folder in your JavaFX folder. If a name of a folder contains spaces, surround the entire file path with quotes.. Apply your changes and close the dialog.

Now you're done! Go ahead, code your JavaFX stuff, then hit run. Voila!

*Official Documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html*