# JavaFX runtime components are missing, even though I already have them in my VM options and Modules

Tags: java, javafx

I am getting this error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I checked multiple solutions on YouTube and StackOverflow such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKI7tDozPog and [Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application with JDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478675/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-run-this-appli)

As a result, I followed their advice and added what they said to my VM options. This is what I have in my run configuration

[image]

Despite this however, I still encountered this error.

[image]

Here are some code that I have:

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>proj4</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.proj4/application.proj4.PizzeriaApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My application

```
package application.proj4;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PizzeriaApplication extends Application
{
    /**
     * This method is the start of the application.
     * @param stage A Stage object
     * @throws IOException An IOException object
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(PizzeriaApplication.class.getResource("pizzeria-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 600);
        stage.setTitle("RU Pizzeria");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        //This closes the entire application if the Main Menu window is closed
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(t ->
        {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method launches the application.
     * @param args An array of Strings
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch();
    }
}
```

My dependencies in modules of project structure

[image]

A response is appreciated.

Comment: Within an hour is quick for me I guess. I edited the post though. @ScaryWombat

Comment: If you put the full error messages formatted as multi-line code text in the question (not as screenshots), as well as the command used to run the app (also formatted as code) it is easier to help troubleshoot issues.

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please

Comment: @jewelsea, I did put the error message as text, it's the first code box.

Comment: But you didn’t put the text of the command used to run the app, which was the crucial thing for being able to understand and answer this question.  The full command line is displayed by idea in the [console tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html) when you run the program, you can copy text from there, you don’t need to screenshot it and the screenshot does not display the full command line which was used, so it doesn’t help understand or solve the problem.

Comment: @jewelsea I see thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I found out why this is occurring.

I put the module path and add modules in the program arguments and not in the vm options, which is what is causing the red issue.

Now I am encountering a "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer" issue now.

Comment: Suggest you close this question given you have resolved it and post another if you are still having an issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't resolve my own question with an answer for two days. I also have to wait 90 minutes to post another question.

Comment: You might like to take a look at my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630618/intellij-ide-how-to-add-sdk/66630770#66630770 I have found this to be a better way to add JavaFX to a project than altering the VM options - and more in line with the expected use of java modules

Comment: Close this question if you found the solution

Comment: @HarryCoder No, the question does not need to be closed.  It can be [self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).   And I believe the current self-answer will be useful for future developers who may well experience the same issue.  After a couple of days, when the system allows it, the self-answer can be marked correct by Josh S.

Comment: For thee boot layer initialization issue, probably your module path is wrong, see [Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module. FindException: Module javafx.controls not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66287593/1155209).  Looking at the module path used in your question, perhaps it needs to be absolute rather than relative e.g. `/Users/...` instead of `Users/...`.

Answer (score 3):

**2023, Answer that will work, for Idea Intellij (will work almost anywhere, very robust)**:

**tl;dr:**

1. You need JavaFX jars. There is no way around that.
2. You download the jars, using Maven
3. You add the jars to the Intellij project
4. You add the jars to VM options

Use Maven to download those jars:

**pom.xml** (some of the stuff there might be redundant, but it works and I don't want to risk it not working for you, so I'd rather post the full file that worked for me):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ConquerJavaFx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ConquerJavaFx</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20-ea+4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>20-ea+4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 
    <build>
        <finalName>ConquerJavaFx</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
                    <stripVersion>false</stripVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Add LIB folder to classPath -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`mvn install` would install the JavaFx depedencies (the `<dependencies>` tag contains the info that will be used at this step).

Then do `mvn package` (the `<build>` tag contains the info that will be used at this step - the plugin that will copy all depedency jars into the `target/lib` folder).

It will create a `lib` folder with JavaFx jars, like this:

```
project root
  src 
    ...
  target
    classes
      ...
    lib
      javafx-base.jar
      javafx-controls.jar
      ...
```

Then in your project go `File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> plus sign + -> java -> go to the target/lib and select all the jars`:

[image]

Now your source code will compile.

However JavaFX devs are evil,so it still won't run (will be the error about runtime components missing). So you need to do this:

`Run -> Edit Configurations -> Modify options`:

Also the proper `Edit Configurations` menu won't appear until you try to run the main class (and fail, since it's JavaFX we're deadling with...)

[image]

[image]

Then select `Add VM options`:

[image]

`VM options` input field will appear:

[image]

and enter

```
--module-path "../target/lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

where `../target/lib` is the full path where your JavaFx jars are located.

in that field

Now it should run! I hope I saved you hours of frustration.

Polite words can't describe my emotions about the person who made the decision to remove JavaFX from Java!

**Notes**:

I tested in in a project **without** `module-info.java`

And the project in Idea Intellij was created as the simple one:

`File - New -> Project -> New Project`:

[image]

and my code in Intellij looks like this:

```
src (blue folder, sources root)
  somepackage1
     some codes
  somepackage2
     some codes
  Main.java (contains the start and the main method)
```

So the `Main` class is not in any package. I don't know how important it is, but considering the minefield that is making JavaFx to run, I'd rather let you know that.

Comment: Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77260682/when-launching-bat-file-get-runtime-components-missing-error?

Comment: @JeffCook I'm sorry, I'm not a specialist on JavaFX runtime errors ; ( That's why I made this answer in the first place, so that I could remind myself and others how to do it. Did you manage to solve your problem? I'm sorry my answer didn't help ; (

Comment: This does not need to be so complex.  You can use the [new JavaFX wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) to create a new modular JavaFX project.  Or, if you don't want to create a modular project and don't want to do that by modifying a project generated by the Idea JavaFX wizard, then you can follow the official instructions at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij)