# When launching bat file, get runtime components missing error

Tags: java, java-11

I am using Open JDK 11 and uses JavaFX for one of my module which maven based. I can build the project and creating jar file using shade plugins but when I am launching the bat file its giving me below error

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

C:\users\App_Java11>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The bat file which I am using

```
@set JAVA_BIN=C:/Program Files/openjdk-jdk-11/bin/java
@set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -module-path "C:/jars/lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
@"%JAVA_BIN%" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="some.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -jar app.jar -Xmx350m
pause
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>XX</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <artifactId>abc-maven-parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>some-app</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.3.21</spring.version>
        <javafx.version>11</javafx.version>
         <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.6</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <!--pluginManagement-->
        <plugins>
             <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer" />
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ComponentsXmlResourceTransformer" />
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.application.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.application.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!--/pluginManagement-->
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gemstone.gemfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gemfire</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Even after adding all modules its not working

Comment: When your module path only consists of `"C:/jars/lib"`, does that mean the JavaFX modules are also stored there? Side note: placing `-Xmx350m` after the `-jar app.jar` makes it a program argument passed to your `main` method. You surely want it to be a JVM argument, so it has to be placed before `-jar`.

Comment: AFAIK, JavaFX modules only support being put on the module path. That means you can not shade them into another jar file.